# Nodejs multer-sftp file upload issue

Tags: node.js

**Node js Code here**

```
  var express = require('express');
    var multer = require('multer');
    var path = require('path');
    var sftpStorage = require('multer-sftp')
    var app = express();
    var port = 3000;

// specify the folder
app.use(express.static(path.join('/home/g457b5jxaq4m/public_html/shiva/upload/, 'uploads')));
// headers and content type
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

var storage = sftpStorage({
     sftp: {
    host: 'ip address',
    port: 22,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
  },
  // destination
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/upload", upload.array("uploads[]", 12), function (req, res) {
  console.log('files', req.files);
  res.send(req.files);
});

var server = app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port %s...", port);
});
```

**Angular Code:**

```
export class NotfoundComponent implements OnInit {

  filesToUpload: Array<File> = [];

  upload() {
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    const files: Array<File> = this.filesToUpload;
    console.log(files);

    for(let i =0; i < files.length; i++){
        formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
    }
    console.log('form data variable :   '+ formData.toString());
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', formData)

        .subscribe(files => console.log('files', files))
}

fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
    this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;

}
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**HMTL**

```
<input id="cin" name="cin" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload a file..." multiple/>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" (click)="upload()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></i>&nbsp;Upload
</button>
```

**Console issue**

[image]

I am trying to upload a file in a remote server with help of Nodejs.
**Frond end** Angular 5 
**Back-end** Node js 
i can upload in local server but when I tried with upload in the remote FTP response seems link internal error. failed to load the following local server node API

Comment: I guess your `res.send(req.files);` is wrong.. It should be `req.send(req.files);` right?

Comment: @DavidR Yes your are correct, thanks for that. but it won't help i guess. it's a response to send to he front end.

Comment: I could see that the upload call hits `http://localhost:3000/upload` which I suspect as invalid because normally it would be looking like, `http://localhost:3000/YOUR_APP_NAME/upload` , If this assumption is correct, then try changing your `cb(null, './uploads/')` as `cb(null, '/uploads/')` (or) `cb(null, 'uploads/')`

Comment: @DavidR

The URL should call how we are using in the code with the request


app.post("/upload", upload.array("uploads[]", 12), function (req, res) {
  console.log('files', req.files);
  res.send(req.files);
});
i called http://localhost:3000/upload like this. i have chance the destination path. but getting the same issue.

Comment: Then, it should definitely be an error with multer and sftp process..

Comment: Can you update your post with your `html` code (or) `.ejs` whatever you have for templating?

Comment: @DavidR I have updated the HTML code above. please have a look

Comment: Seems you've posted the your component (.ts) file. Can you also post your component's html file?

Comment: Updated now. sorry for the miscommunication :S